# Convert this JPQL query to SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

```
SELECT
        depart_id
    FROM
        department
    GROUP BY
        depart_id
    HAVING
        SUM(emp_id IN ('emp1', 'emp2'))

# depart_id emp_id
1a  emp1
1a  emp2
1a  emp3
1a  emp2
2b  emp1
```

problem here is it is throwing exception antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting CLOSE, found 'in'

Comment: Please make this a complete question, by including sample _input_ table/entity data.  Then also show us the exact _output_ you want, and explain what your current SQL query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: table structure is mentioned in question don't bother about result just want no compilation error while converting mentioned query from jpql to sql. This part of query throwing exception **SUM(emp_id IN ('emp1', 'emp2'))**

Comment: `from jpql to sql` ... your title says you want to convert from SQL to JPQL.  This question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for wrong title, Its updated now.

Answer (score 0):

in first I think there is an error in the query as you wrote it:

```
select depart_id from department group by depart_id having sum(emp_id) in ('emp1', 'emp2');
```

SUM needs to be closed and IN is then applied on the result of this sum.

Some help  with CriteriaBuilder ane JPQL can be found [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group).

Comment: first of all this is not working and second by changing from  SUM(emp_id IN ('emp1', 'emp2')) to sum(emp_id) in ('emp1', 'emp2') will change the whole result.Because in this  SUM(emp_id IN ('emp1', 'emp2')) we are first extracting the emp_id which lies under ('emp1', 'emp2') then doing sum but in your query we first doing sum of emp_id and then checking those in ('emp1', 'emp2') which is not even possible.

Comment: Ok ... then just ad emp_id IN ('emp1', 'emp2') to WHERE condition. And the query will just return lines where this condition is "true". If you want to select count of lines for particular department just select COUNT(*).

Comment: i can not change the query structure as this will change the result of query and as per JPQL doc Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause check this link https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries. But i am not sure wether aggregate over aggregate is legal or not.

Comment: Ok what is the SUM there for? You want to select the count of emp? Or what is it there for? May be when you provide something like expected result someone can help you here ...

Comment: this is pretty complicated query its first checking how many emp id are matching for given id in this case emp1 and emp2 then doing sum of that so with count you will get 3 and 2 but with sum you will get only 2.